# maven - while downloading dependencies Maven skip some servers defined in settings.xml

Tags: maven

I cannot resolve my dependencies while using `mvn clean install -U -X`, even when I specify `-Pcentral` profile which includes the repository which has that dependency. The root cause exception is:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.brand.esb:common:pom:0.10 in artifactory-redhat-ga (https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga)
```

I see this dependency is in `artifactory-foo-staging`, and this is defined in my `~/.m2/settings.xml`, but I don't see Maven downloading from it. The credentials are good, verified with private mode.

```bash
Downloading from artifactory-foo-release: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release/com/example/brand/product/test/jms-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
Downloading from apache.snapshots: https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/com/example/brand/product/test/jms-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/myself/.m2/repository/com/example/brand/product/test/jms-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/myself/.m2/repository/com/example/brand/product/test/jms-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in artifactory-foo-release (https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of artifactory-foo-release has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find com.example.brand.product.test:jms-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in https://repository.apache.org/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /home/myself/.m2/repository/com/brand/esb/common/0.10/common-0.10.pom from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, disabled), artifactory-redhat-ga (https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga, default, releases), artifactory-foo-release (https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release, default, releases+snapshots), apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga
Downloading from artifactory-redhat-ga: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga/com/brand/esb/common/0.10/common-0.10.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/myself/.m2/repository/com/brand/esb/common/0.10/common-0.10.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release with username=myself, password=***
Downloading from artifactory-foo-release: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release/com/brand/esb/common/0.10/common-0.10.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/myself/.m2/repository/com/brand/esb/common/0.10/common-0.10.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/release with username=myself, password=***
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
```

The settings:

```xml
<settings>
    <!-- if you need http connection, enable it and don't block -->
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
          <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
          <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
          <url>file:/home/myself/.m2/repository/</url>
          <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory-redhat-ga</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory-foo-release</id>
            <username>myself</username>
            <password>{encoded}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory-foo-staging</id>
            <username>myself</username>
            <password>{encoded}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory-foo-external</id>
            <username>myself</username>
            <password>{encoded}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory-foo-dev</id>
            <username>myself</username>
            <password>{encoded}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>confluent</id>
                    <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>central</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory-redhat-ga</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory-foo-release</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/proj-foo-release</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory-foo-staging</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/proj-foo-staging</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory-foo-external</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/proj-foo-external</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory-foo-dev</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/proj-foo-dev</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven</url>
             <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
             </releases>
             <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
             </snapshots>
          </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>artifactory-redhat-ga</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/redhat-ga</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>artifactory-foo-release</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/proj-foo-release</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <sonar.host.url>
                    https://sonarqube.bar.example.com
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Do you know why?

Actually external and dev repos are also skipped. How to check all the repos defined in settings.xml?

Comment: Configure your Artifactory to handle that...that the easiest and most practical way to do...

Comment: I don't understand, can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Configure a single group in Artifactory to handle all the different repositories... furthermore if I read things like: `file:/home/myself/.m2/repository` there is something really wrong... Please contact your artifactory admin etc...

Comment: OK that part is for skipping HTTP, I can comment that out. And I have used that profile `central` for different repos, I don't see a question here actually.. You know you cannot always find the admin of artifactory and change sth in 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, things start to work when I manually download the pom/jars into my local repository paths, following the convention of naming patterns of Maven. Still not understanding but my local .m2 repo can resolve them now.

There was a pom/jar but somehow it does not work so I removed it. I also had to remove the `xxx.pom.lastUpdated`, `xxx.pom.sha1`, and `_remote.repositories` files.